# How to discover where is the data from deployd

Tags: node.js, mongodb, terminal, deployd

I'm using deployd on a project and I see the data in my api, but when I search for the DB on mongo shell I can't see that, maybe the deployd has created another instance for mongo but I can't find it. 
Some one could help me?

This is the Image from my mongo shell

[image: Image from mongo shell]

This is my image from my deployd API

[image: Image from deploys API]
I'm using MAC OS

Answer (score 0):

Yup, Deployd creates a mongodb mongodb://localhost:27017/interface
So search for MongoDB install folder and Default 'Data' folder , there you will find 'interface' db.

You can set your own 'data' folder in mongodb like

```
"C:\Program Files\MongoDB\Server\3.4\bin\mongod.exe" --auth --dbpath "C:\DATABASES\MongoDB\data"
```

and give the reference in deployd server.js (or any startup file)

```
var deployd = require('deployd')
, options = {port: 3000,env: 'development',
db: {
connectionString: 'mongodb://localhost:27017/interface'

}
};

var dpd = deployd(options);

dpd.listen();
```